# Check if function return false in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

I got in trouble trying to check if a function return false.

I'm wrintng a script to upload a picture file when the user select the filw in the input form field.

So the html form is the following:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form" role="form">
<input type="hidden" id="register-id" name="id" value="">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select image</label>
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" name="filedata" class="custom-file-input" id="picture" accept="image/*">
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="picture">Choose file</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress mb-2 progress-sm">
            <div id="file-progress-bar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

The javascript code to get the file on input change is the following, the code should start some file check

```
$('#picture').on('change', function() {
    let picture = this.files[0];

    if(!checkFile(picture)) {
        alert("Check file not passed");
        return false;
    }
});
```

The issue is: the script stop execution and show the alert message "Check file not passed", even if the called checkFile function doesn't return fasle since the file pass all checks.
What's wrong? Thanks a lot.

Below the checkFile function

```
function checkFile(picture) {
    let imagetype = picture.type;
    console.log('Picture type ' + imagetype);
    let match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
    if(!((imagetype==match[0]) || (imagetype==match[1]) || (imagetype==match[2])))
    {
        console.log('Matching picture type failed');
        return false;
    }

    let reg=/(.jpg|.gif|.png)$/;
    console.log('Picture name is ' + picture.name);
    if (!reg.test(picture.name)) {
        console.log('Check picture name failed');
        return false;
    }
    console.log('Picture size is ' + picture.size);
    if (picture.size > 204800) {
        console.log('Check picture size failed');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there a better strategy to check the file before upload?

Thanks a lot for any feedback

Comment: If you don't add `return true;` at the end of the function, it will return `undefined`, which will test as "falsy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return `true` at the end of your function. If you will not return anything from the function it will return `undefined` which is a falsy value.

```js
function checkFile(picture) {
  let imagetype = picture.type;

  // ... rest of the code

  if (picture.size > 204800) {
    console.log('Check picture size failed');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Or you can change the condition to match exactly with `false`

```
if(checkFile(picture) === false) {
  alert("Check file not passed");
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return true when all checks have passed.

```js
function checkFile(picture) {
    [...previousLines]

    return true;
}
```